# Content fit screen when minimizing?

Tags: html, css

I am new to html and css and i need some help.

When I shrink my website, I want the contents to be changed so that it looks like on a phone or ipad. I have an example here.( http://www.osynlig.se/ ) Try to minimize the website as much as possible, you can see that the content modifies to fit the size of the browser and it is this I do not know how to do. If you can send a link to a website that explains how to do it or if you could write a comment, it would be greatly appreciated

Srry if i have mistyped anything i am from sweden :3.
thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is known as responsive web design. You can do it yourself with media queries in css like this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .facet_sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

That sets the display to none for the facet_sidebar class if the width is less than 600 px.

Or you can use a library that already takes care of it for you, Bootstrap is a very popular option http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: I have been searching forever and then i found this website and asked a question. And got instanly a answer. thank you so much!